# DrawableLeft in center with text

Tags: android, android-layout

I can't center my drawableLeft icon.
I can easily put icon on the left of text, but if I set gravity to center, then only text is centered, but no icon.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/patient_list_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/patientList"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_icon_two_heads"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    style="@style/darkBlueButtonWithImage"/>
```

This is what I want:
[image]
This is what I have:
[image]

```
<style name="darkBlueButtonWithImage">
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/radius_dark_blue_button</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|left</item>
    <item name="android:drawableTint">@color/white</item> <!-- has to be set in activity.java -->
</style>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use drawable padding

Comment: @JanardhanR Using padding would make it impossible if the button's text is dynamic.

Comment: You have in your style gravity set to `center_vertical|left`. Try replacing it with `center`

Comment: make custom view instead of button!!

Comment: @JaydeepPatel really… you're going to make a custom view just for that.

Comment: yah of course, if developer wants to. it is Textview inside viewgroup simple.

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason, I don't think making a custom view is worth, ever. There are good reasons, but this is definitely not one of them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally, after all these years, we have possibility to achieve such behavior in simple and intuitive way.
All you have to do is use [MaterialButton](https://material.io/develop/android/components/buttons) from Google Material library. Then use style with icon. After that you can use `app:iconGravity` property and set it to `textStart`

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some text"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        app:icon="@drawable/some_icon" />
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest solution IMO:

```
yourButtonView.text = SpannableString(" ${getString(R.string.your_string)}").apply {
            setSpan(
                ImageSpan(requireContext(), R.drawable.your_icon),
                0,
                1,
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
            )
        }
```

Is a bit hacky? Maybe. Does it work with every button (MaterialButton, AppCompatButton, Button, etc)? It does.

I prefer this rather than going with all the hassle of creating a custom view or something like that.

Comment: thx, in our project we had a custom button which could inherit from MaterialButton neither doing a new layout with ImageView and TextView, was an option (well, it was but very time and money consuming to mimic all our current tv button behaviour). Your solution (or hack :) ) worked well ad solved the problem -thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

After giving Google's approach a try over 9000 times, I almost always ended up using a ViewGroup to put both side by side, particularly a `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` and then adding an ImageView and a TextView. It's lame, but drawableStart/End have so many missing features that you'll waste a lot of time before you realize "you can't do it".

Alignments, tinting, Vectors, etc. All those things are harder or impossible with the "built in" drawable.

Comment: Ok give Google another chance, just the last one, aaand, nope.

Answer (score 3):

Using `Button` attributes `android:drawableLeft` and `android:drawablePadding` you won't be able to get your expected result. You can create a custom button using `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`, `TextView` and `ImageView`. Use `<selector>` to define your button state(`normal/pressed`) behavior.

**Here is an working example. Try this:**

```
<!--- Custom Button -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/patient_list_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button_selector">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_refresh"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:text="CUSTOM BUTTON"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**custom_button_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/bg_custom_button_pressed" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/bg_custom_button_pressed" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/bg_custom_button_normal" />
</selector>
```

**bg_custom_button_normal.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <!-- view background color -->
    <solid
        android:color="#01A1DD" >
    </solid>

    <!-- Here is the corner radius -->
    <corners android:radius="8dp" >
    </corners>

</shape>
```

**bg_custom_button_pressed.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <!-- view background color -->
    <solid
        android:color="#303F9F">
    </solid>

    <!-- Here is the corner radius -->
    <corners android:radius="8dp" >
    </corners>

</shape>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]
Hope this will help~

Comment: @MarekCzaplicki My pleasure :). You can use Android studio `"Image Asset"` option to get icons. Just right click on your any project `"File > New > Image Asset"`. Thank you~

Comment: @Marek: May I know the reason of rejecting this answer from Accepted Answer?

Answer (score 2):

a) Increase "paddingLeft" value and shrink or remove "drawablePadding" in your case, adjust the value to a proper one; for example:

```
android:paddingLeft="50dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
```

b) Use a custom view.

Answer (score 0):

A bit hacky solution:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_whatsapp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/tv_call"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_completed_message_desc"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/rs_dp_13"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rs_dp_12"
    android:background="@drawable/rs_dark_teal_rectangle_bg"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_teal"
    **android:paddingHorizontal="38dp"**
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    **android:drawableStart="@drawable/rs_user_journey_whatsapp_icon"**
    **android:drawableLeft="@drawable/rs_user_journey_whatsapp_icon"**
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:letterSpacing="0.04"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    **android:gravity="center_vertical|end"**
    android:text="Whatsapp"/>
```

Setting horizontal padding along with gravity as center_vertical|end will achieve the required behaviour. You can increase/decrease the padding as per requirement.